# Hive Compute Statistic HDP 2.6

Tags: hive, statistics, hdp

Trying to see statistics on a particular column. I executed the `ANALYZE` command first and then tried to see the stats by `DESCRIBE FORMATTED <table_name> <col_name>`.

I cant see any values in this. Any idea why its not showing any values?

I tried `MSCK` and analyzed the table again and checked for stats. No luck so far.

```
hive> desc extended testdb.table order_dispatch_diff;
OK
order_dispatch_diff     int                     from deserializer
Time taken: 0.041 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it with `FOR COLUMNS` parameter:

```
ANALYZE TABLE testdb.table COMPUTE STATISTICS FOR COLUMNS;
```

Then use `DESCRIBE FORMATTED testdb.table order_dispatch_diff;` to display statistics.

See [Column Statistics](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Column+Statistics+in+Hive) docs for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Below Statement worked for me finally .

hive> desc formatted testdb.table col_name partition (data_dt='20180715');